# variables from config.py not updated

Tags: python

i have 2 "real" modules + the config.py used to host variables shared amongst the 2 first modules

in config.py, the string variables are initialized with '' (empty string)

the first module launches a selenium webdriver, and i retrieve the command_executor._url and session_id in order to be able to pilot the very same driver in the other module

so in the module #1, i do :

```
import config

# code to launch of the selenium webdriver with specific parameters

config.ceu = driver.command_executor._url
config.si = driver.session_id
```

in the module #2, i try to retrieve these updated variable in a function, **which is only called after the variables have been updated !** but it returns empty strings

my module #2 code :

```
import config

def my_function():
   print(config.ceu)
   print(config.si)

# some code that takes time including my_function() : once again, the call to my_function() is made after the launch of the browser in the first module, and by a way of consequence the assignment of the values to the variables
```

so why are the variables not updated, and correctly printed in module #2 ?

Comment: "i try to retrieve these updated variable in a function, which is only called after the variables have been updated !" In your own words, why do you expect the code in module #1 to run before module #2 attempts the `import`?

Comment: Are the two modules both parts of a package? How do you run these to "real" modules? Does module #1 call into module #2 somehow? Or are you just manually executing them via CLI, respectively?

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. If you want to use the same driver, simply pass the ``driver`` object as parameter around.

Comment: the two python scripts are called from a .bat, one after the other : the first one (selenium webdriver launch) executes quite quickly so the variable are quickly set, while the second module performs many tasks and only calls the function when my algo finds a match (can take some time)

Comment: @MikeScotty i read quite a lot of posts, and it seemed like the only way to use the same webdriver...

Comment: Seems we all have some different understanding of naming conventions here. If you're "calling" 2 python modules spearately, you're basically talking about 2 different **applications**, running at different times. In that case, you have to store the information somewhere both applications can access it, e.g. a file. Changing values in a module at run time will only affect the currently active application, not any other application that loads the same module (at a later point). Does not matter if the applications are started from the same bat.

Comment: @MikeScotty OK got it, thanks for the clear explanation

Comment: jeremoquai: Python has a [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module in its standard library for reading and writing persistent configuration files which you might want to take a look at.